# How to keep select2 dropdown event open when clicking on another select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I have multiple select2 dropdowns. Whenever the select2 dropdown is open, I want to add class to my div.

For this I am using open and close event of select2. The below code works fine when you open a select2 dropdown and close it. But it does not work if you have a select2 dropdown open and click on another select2 dropdown. In that case it detects close event.

```
$('select').on('select2:open', function (e) {
    $('.a').addClass("header-index");
});
$('select').on('select2:close', function (e) {
    $('.a').removeClass("header-index");
});
```

How do I make sure that when select2 dropdown is open and user tries to open another select2 dropdown then close event is not fired.

Comment: Can you share your html code?

Comment: do you want to add/remove class for only one select2 or atleast one select2 to be opened ?

Comment: @User863 I want to add class for all select2 when they are open and remove class when closed

Answer (score 0):

Try binding elements with IDs

```
$('#select1').on('select2:open', function (e) {
    $('.a').addClass("header-index");
});
$('#select1').on('select2:close', function (e) {
    $('.a').removeClass("header-index");
});
```

or bind elements with index

```
$('select')[0].on('select2:open', function (e) {
    $('.a').addClass("header-index");
});
$('select')[1].on('select2:close', function (e) {
    $('.a').removeClass("header-index");
});
```

Comment: No, they are not dynamic

Comment: then you can bind each select elements using $.each

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$(".js-example-events").select2();

$('.js-example-events').on("select2:open", function () { alert(1); });
$('.js-example-events').on("select2:close", function () { alert(2); });

<select class="js-example-events">
<option>Select</option>
<option>Select1</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/4qucL9h3/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` and `select2('isOpen')`

```js
$('select').select2()

$(document).on('select2:open select2:close', function(e) {
  let opened = $('select').filter(function() {
    return $(this).select2('isOpen')
  }).length
  
  $('.a').toggleClass('header-index', Boolean(opened));
});
```

```css
.header-index {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="a">header-index</div>

<select style="width: 300px">
  <option value="JAN">January</option>
  <option value="FEB">February</option>
  <option value="MAR">March</option>
  <option value="APR">April</option>
  <option value="MAY">May</option>
  <option value="JUN">June</option>
  <option value="JUL">July</option>
  <option value="AUG">August</option>
  <option value="SEP">September</option>
  <option value="OCT">October</option>
  <option value="NOV">November</option>
  <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>


<select style="width: 300px">
  <option value="JAN">January</option>
  <option value="FEB">February</option>
  <option value="MAR">March</option>
  <option value="APR">April</option>
  <option value="MAY">May</option>
  <option value="JUN">June</option>
  <option value="JUL">July</option>
  <option value="AUG">August</option>
  <option value="SEP">September</option>
  <option value="OCT">October</option>
  <option value="NOV">November</option>
  <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```